# Transparent colored foreground in HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

Is there a way to have a transparent foreground color in a web page? I'm basically trying to put a redish feeling to a web site.

Edit: To bring clarity: I don't mean a font color. I want a color to cover the whole page with  high transparency.

Comment: What do you think as "foreground color"? There is no such thing in html.

Comment: do you mean a color in front of the whole page? covering up other stuff? or a background color?

Comment: @PeterHorvath I think he means font color.

Comment: @Mickael what's the point of transparent font color? It will just be invisible.

Comment: A color in front of the whole page. @PeterHorvath I know that. I'm looking for a way to mimic a foreground color.

Comment: The idea is to give a colored 'fog' so to speak to the web page.

Comment: How would you tell the difference from using a dark or light red background-color?

Comment: I guess you mean a color filter like this http://www.impressivewebs.com/image-tint-blend-css/, although I imagine you will have some z-index difficulties applying this to an entire page

Answer (score 4):

Pretty simple. First, put this element at the top of your `body` tag:

```
<div id="foreground"></div>
```

and then this styling in a `style` tag somewhere:

```
#foreground{
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#ff0000;
    opacity:0.3;
    pointer-events:none;
}
```

Comment: Assuming he doesn't have any controls (menu's etc.) which will be inaccessible due to this div covering the whole page...

Comment: add pointer-events:none; and you're good to go!